# Tkinter's button can't change border color

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Here's my Tkinter code:

```
Photoshop = Tkinter.Button(root, 
    text = 'Photoshop',
    fg = '#37d3ff',
    bg = '#001d26',
    bd =  10, 
    highlightthickness=4, 
    highlightcolor="#37d3ff", 
    highlightbackground="#37d3ff", 
    borderwidth=4)
```

However, after I grid my Button, the color of border doesn't shows up. Instead, it used default grey.

Comment: this is not a `human-readable` code

Comment: you can't change the border color with tkinter. `highlightcolor` and `highlightbackground` aren't the border colors, they are colors for the highlight ring which shows when the button  has focus.

Answer (score 8):

You may place the button inside its own frame like this:

```
buttonborder = Tkinter.Frame(root,
                             highlightbackground="#37d3ff",
                             highlightcolor="#37d3ff",
                             highlightthickness=4,
                             bd=0)

photoshop = Tkinter.Button(buttonborder, 
                           text='Photoshop',
                           fg='#37d3ff',
                           bg='#001d26')
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

Photoshop = tk.Button(root, text = 'Photoshop',
                      fg = '#37d3ff',
                      bg = '#001d26',
                      bd =  10, 
                      highlightthickness=4, 
                      highlightcolor="#37d3ff", 
                      highlightbackground="#37d3ff", 
                      borderwidth=4)
Photoshop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add your widget to a Frame and make the Frame's highlight background to be the color you want for your widget's border. CODE Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

buttonborder = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground="#37d3ff",
                                  highlightthickness=3, bd=0)
photoshop = tk.Button(buttonborder, text='Photoshop', fg='#37d3ff')
photoshop.pack()
buttonborder.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `LabelFrame()` and `relief`.
Works in windows.

```
from tkinter import *

App = Tk()

Border = LabelFrame(App,
                    bd=5, #<- Borderwidth.
                    bg="blue", #<- Border color.
                    relief=FLAT)
Border.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

Btn1 = Button(Border, #<- in Border Widget.
              text="Button", 
              font="Arial 16 bold",
              width=16,
              bg="red",
              fg="white",
              relief=FLAT)
Btn1.pack()

App.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to do this unfortunately, But you sure can hack around and place a tkinter Frame that is just a little bigger than the actual button to set them apart by using the frame as a coloured border, Something like this. Should work on Win and Mac or any other OS's..
(assuming you already know how to work with tkinter root window..)
`borderFrame = Frame(root, bg="red(your desired colour of choice)")
borderFrame.pack(padx=21, pady=21)

```
 button = Button(borderFrame, bg="blue",text="click me", relief='flat')
 button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)`
```