# Changing the colour of button border with python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to change the color of my border on this button however it does nothing or gives me a grey border.

```
self._lqbutton = tk.Button(self._longquestionframe, 
                           text="TEST",
                           bg="blue", fg="#fff",
                           highlightbackground="red",
                           highlightcolor="red",
                           highlightthickness=4,
                           relief=tk.SOLID,
                           borderwidth="4")
self._lqbutton.pack()
```

I have also tried using relief=tk.FLAT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter's button can't change border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156055/tkinters-button-cant-change-border-color)

Answer (score 2):

Managed to achieve the effect by placing it inside its own frame and changing the frame attributes.

```
self._lqbuttonborder = tk.Frame(self._longquestionframe,
                                    highlightbackground="#bce8f1",
                                    highlightcolor="#bce8f1",
                                    highlightthickness=1,
                                    bd=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the border color of a widget. The `highlightcolor` and `highlightbackground` attributes changes the color of the *highlight ring*, which is the border-like decoration that appears only when the widget has focus.