# why I can't change background color of a tkinter button using python on a Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I have a simple python code on my Mac, tryin to change background color of a button, in a tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
w=Tk()
def change():
    b.config(bg='yellow')
b=Button(w,text='CHANGE',command=change)
b.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156055/tkinters-button-cant-change-border-color/47156214#47156214) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is link: [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/)

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkmacosx import Button

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x150')
B0 = Button(root, text='Button')
B0.pack(padx=20, pady=(20,0))
B1 = Button(root, text='Button', bg='#ADEFD1',
            fg='#00203F', borderless=1)
B1.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
B2 = Button(root, text='Button', bg='#E69A8D',
            fg='#5F4B8B', borderless=1,
            activebackground=('#AE0E36', '#D32E5E'),
            activeforeground='#E69A8D')
B2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter uses tk, and tk uses native toolkits, and on OSX the native toolkits don't allow you to change the background color of buttons.

Comment: thx. but so why I can change foreground color of the button but not background?

Comment: @Tommy you'll probably have to ask Apple that question.