# python 3 - Mac OS - tkinter for Label and Entry not working

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Label and Editor not visible in black ground in Mac OS,
[image]

Code

```
from tkinter import *
def main():
root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
num = StringVar()
l1=Label(root,text='strike',highlightbackground="Yellow", fg="Blue", highlightthickness=30)
t1 = Entry(root,textvariable=num, highlightbackground="Yellow", fg="Blue", highlightthickness=30)
btn=Button(root, text='Click Me', bd='50',command = startorder, highlightbackground="Yellow", fg="Blue", highlightthickness=30)

l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
t1.grid(row=0,column=1)
btn.grid(row=1,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried many options available in internet. but cant change the bgcolor. I know button got issue but what about Label and Texteditor? Python 3

Comment: Why main function has no indent.

Comment: And where you call the main function.

Comment: I don't personally use mac, but searching this up there seems to be a lot of issues running tkinter on it, specifically regarding colour adjustment [as noted in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70236235/12282048). You might want to refer to [this module](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/) to see if it helps at all, sorry i can't test it myself.

Comment: I just copied the code snippet. not the entire program. I was struggling to post this in stackflow hence no indent

Comment: @dwrl1209 thank you, I tried to install it as per instruction. But it was showing some tkinter error for spyder IDE while executing python -m tkmacosx