# Tkinter datepicker calendar not showing in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am making a Python program that uses the DateEntry widget in Tkinter. However, when I run the program, I can't see the calendar. My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry  # Make sure to install tkcalendar using: pip install tkcalendar

def on_date_select():
    selected_date = cal.get_date()
    print(f"Selected date: {selected_date}")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Datepicker Example")

# Create a Calendar
cal = DateEntry(root, width=12, background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Create a button to get the selected date
btn_get_date = ttk.Button(root, text="Get Selected Date", command=on_date_select)
btn_get_date.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[Here’s what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjl4W.png)

I have tried many solutions on the internet all to no avail. How do I fix this problem?

Note: I’m  using m1 MacBook Air

Comment: Try reinstalling Python from python.org.

Comment: Does your program throw any errors?

Comment: it doesn't throw any errors TT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why I can't change background color of a tkinter button using python on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233417/why-i-cant-change-background-color-of-a-tkinter-button-using-python-on-a-mac)

Comment: i've tried without changing colors but still not workin...T.T