# Why does a black background appears when there seems to be no issue with the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, user-interface, tkinter

So I am just learning the basics of python GUI and was learning to use tkinter but when I created label and tried to add both text and image inside the label and compound them a black screen appears. When i use them singly either image only or text only it works tho. I also tried decreasing the size of the image but does not seem to work.

here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Arjan's GUI")
icon = PhotoImage(file="klipartz.com.png")
window.iconphoto(True, icon)
window.config(background="#00ffab")

# Keep a global reference to the image
photo1 = PhotoImage(file="Untitled-1.png")

label1 = Label(window,
              text="h",
               font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'),
               fg='yellow',
               
               relief=RAISED,
               bd=10,
               padx=10,
               pady=10,
               compound='bottom',
               image=photo1)
  
label1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I have tried decreasing the size of the image too but does not work. I have also tried to remove the background color from black to nothing thinking it was due to that but does not seem to work.

Comment: Is that your EXACT code, or did you create the label inside a function?  There's a design flaw in Tkinter such that it doesn't automatically keep a reference to images like that, so if you do that in a function, the bitmap is deleted when the function returns.  You need to store it in a global.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why I can't change background color of a tkinter button using python on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70233417/why-i-cant-change-background-color-of-a-tkinter-button-using-python-on-a-mac)